# Sample from list of lists until condition is met

Tags: python, random, psychopy

I have a list of lists that I am randomly choosing a value from. The issue I am having now is that since the loop I wrote is using `random.choice()` there is the possibility that a given value won't be present, which will cause an error in downstream code. So I basically want to sample from this list of lists until the final list has at least one occurrence of each value (so at least one occurrence of 1-8).

Below is my current code and the output list for `probe` which doesn't include a single occurrence of `3` in this iteration, which will cause the subsequent code to fail.

Some restrictions I have:

1. The final list `probe` needs to be only 16 items.
2. One of the two values needs to be picked at each index because it codes for a later stimulus. So for example, `probe[0]` in this case needs to be either `7` or `6` and `probe[15]` needs to be either `3` or `2`. But still with the condition that across all indexes, 1-8 appears at least once.

```
probe_list = [['7', '6'], ['5', '8'], ['3', '2'], ['1', '4'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['5', '8'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['5', '8'], ['3', '2']]
```

```
probe=[]
for i in range(len(probe_list)):
    choose = random.choice(probe_list[i])
    probe.append(choose)
```

```
probe = ['7', '8', '2', '1', '6', '1', '5', '6', '4', '2', '7', '4', '6', '4', '8', '2']
```

Comment: You have a list of lists not a list of tuples. Lists are mutable while tuples are immutable.

Comment: Okay, I updated my original post.

Comment: It seems like you want a random shuffling of the items in the list rather than a sampling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `set`, which contains all values which are already in the `probe` in the current "run". Then you could always check, whether the size of the `set` is `8`. If you begin a new "run", then you have to `clear()` the `set` and the `probe`.

```
import random 

probe_list = [['7', '6'], ['5', '8'], ['3', '2'], ['1', '4'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['5', '8'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['3', '2'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['7', '6'], ['1', '4'], ['5', '8'], ['3', '2']]

probe=[]

while True:
   contained=set()
   probe = []
   for i in range(len(probe_list)):
        choose = random.choice(probe_list[i])
        contained.add(choose)
        probe.append(choose)
   if len(contained) == 8:
        break

print(probe, len(probe), len(set(probe)))
```

It would alway ensure, that the length of the probe is 16 and the number of unique items in the probe is 8.
For example the output:

```
['7', '5', '2', '4', '6', '1', '8', '7', '1', '3', '6', '4', '6', '1', '5', '3'] 16 8
```

Comment: The length or ```probe``` is relevant in this case, sorry I didn't initially state that. I updated my post with the 2 restrictions that need to be followed. So the final length of ```probe``` and that each index is one of the two values, but there 1-8 appears at least once. So ```probe``` should contain 16 elements, with the value at each index being one of the two from ```probe_list```, while making sure each value appears at least one time in ```probe```